# Java - Make stage not react to user interaction

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I want my whole program to stop reacting to user interaction while som code is being run.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
stage.getScene().getRoot().setDisable(true);
```

and of course set it back to `false` when your background process completes.